# Mosaico template auto sending

Tags: cron, mosaico, cron-job

I am trying to send out a Mosaico template on Civicrm. I have scheduled it on a certain day. However, I realise that the execution does not work. It is forever on the "Scheduled" state. I believe this has got to do something with the cron. Can anyone asssist me withi this please?
[image]

Comment: as a stop gap have you tried running the Scheduled Job manually

Comment: ah - a colleague just wrote this "Looks like this is a civicrm bug which replicates when you create a reminder with an absolute date instead of a relative date. Eg this reminder was set for absolute date 30th October - I've fixed this in core. Please let me know if you notice any issues in the reminder. I'll then PR it to civi core for the community review"

Comment: I will see if i can dig out the fix and share with you if you are then able to test

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [the documentation for setting up scheduled jobs](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/)? It looks complicated because there are several ways to set this up depending on your hosting environment.  You will also find multiple similar questions on here.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly related to the fix raised in this PR - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28105

Can you please try applying it any verify if it fixes your error? If yes, please comment on the PR.